# Run ssh/scp without .ssh directory or with alternate dir?

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I'm inside chroot, and everytime I scp it keeps telling me:

```
bash-4.2$ scp user@example.com:somefile .
Could not create directory '/.ssh'.
Host key verification failed.
```

Obviously, I have no means to create "/.ssh" dir either, also I've tried to

```
export HOME=/private/
```

(Private dir is user only writable/readable) but it throws same error, that it can't create "/.ssh" so it doesn't even change the path it is trying to create, it always tries to create "/.ssh".

How can I ignore or change the "/.ssh" directory of scp/ssh commands?

Answer (score 3):

I think you could try to do

```
ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -o "UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null" user@server
```

it could work as it won't try do check for a server key... (i have not try this myself)

(inspired from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655815/ssh-on-linux-disabling-host-key-checking-for-hosts-on-local-subnet-known-hosts)