# ssh with an alternative configuration directory?

Tags: ssh, cygwin

Is there any way to run the standard Cygwin `ssh` command with an alternative `$HOME` directory or an alternative `.ssh` configuration directory?

UPDATE: it turns out this is [a duplicate](https://superuser.com/questions/610032/run-ssh-scp-without-ssh-directory-or-with-alternate-dir) question; but it hasn't been answered yet.

Comment: Please explain some more. Why exactly do you need a separate $HOME for cronjobs? What kinds of cronjobs? What would that $HOME be? Can you just run the cron as a different user using `/etc/crontab`? Have you read `man ssh`? Won't the `-F` and/or `-i` options do?

Comment: I've deleted the sentence about the cron jobs. Sorry about that. Please just consider the problem as stated. BTW, a first glance at the source code in `ssh.c` doesn't leave much hope.

Comment: Could you also answer my other questions? If this _is_ about cron there are probably better ways of doing it but why not use the `-F` and `-i` options? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: One question at a time. I was trying to avoid the real question because it takes about 4 paragraphs to explain and people will start picking on all the things I don't mean to ask.

Comment: I think it's cleanest to close this question (although I would *really* like to know the answer, looks like my only option is to compile ssh from source); I'll try to ask the other question in a second attempt. Thank you.

Comment: OK, but my guess is you are trying to copy things in which case `rsync` can do it or that you need a specific identity keyfile in which case the `-i` option would do it or a specific config file in which case the `-F` option would do it. Suit yourself though.

Comment: Yes, `rsync` is what I want to use this for.

Comment: Then post a question asking about that or read `man rsync` it has various options for ssh identities.

Comment: The problem is that my `$HOME` is on a network drive, which `ssh` can deal with just fine, except when running from `cron`.

Comment: Please post a question explaining the situation. You might be able to fix it by specifying a different shell for `cron` or by manually mounting the drive in the crontab or by various options.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11059/discussion-between-reinierpost-and-terdon)

Comment: I solved the problem by writing a wrapper script that actually changes the user's `$HOME` (it's a symlink), executes the wrapped command, then changes it back; and using that in my `cron` job.  It's a hack but it will do.

Comment: Nice! Could you write that up as an answer and accept it?

Comment: It isn't an answer; it's a workaround to the lack of an answer.